Limit on width of a figure when making word document from Rmarkdown
I have an Rmarkdown that I am trying to render to a word document. I have an image that I would like to take up the full width of the page and I am specifying the width as an argument when I include the markdown. However, regardless of what I do, I can't seem to get the figure to be wider than 14.82cm. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Here's a reprex. Save the following RMarkdown somewhere.
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  word_document: default
date: '2024-04-23'
---

Some text.

![5cm wide figure](Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png){ width=5cm }

![14cm wide figure](Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png){ width=14cm }

![15cm wide figure](Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png){ width=15cm }

![17cm wide figure](Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png){ width=17cm }

![100% wide figure](Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png){ width=100% }

You'll also need to save this figure in the working directory as Danmark_v2024a_Figure_04.png - this is the figure that I am trying to include. Once you've got it setup, use Rstudio to knit it to Word. Then open the resulting word doc - you'll see that the width of the largest figures is limited to 14.82cm.
How do I get a "full-width" 17cm wide figure?


Explicit width above the text width are always taken to mean "text width", i.e., the width of the text column. Relative widths like 100% are relative to this text width. Note that relative widths can be more than 100%. A size like 120% will make the image bigger, and it will grow into the right page margin.
However, there is no (easy) way to make the image take up space in the left margin, so making it span the whole page width is not possible. (Technically, one could find a way to do this with a pandoc Lua filter, put it'd be forbiddingly hard).
The officer package could be helpful, but I don't think the above use-case is supported. I don't know the package very well though, and I might be wrong.

Ok, thanks. But how is the "text width" calculated. The output docxis in the "Letter" format, and is 21.59cm wide. The margins are 2cm on either side, giving an available "text width" of 17.59cm as I read it. But the maximum width of the figures is 14.82cm. What accounts for the other 2.77cm?

@MarkPayne That's a good question, I don't have an answer. All I can say is that pandoc calculates the text width by taking the page width and then subtracting the width of the left and right margin. Maybe it there's a problem with that logic somewhere. You could report an issue (but we are pretty "understaffed" right now, so it might take a while).
